# Apollo Query with param

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I would like to add parameter on Query using react-apollo.

My actual query is this :

```
const GET_USER_PLAYIST = gql`
  query Playlist($id: ID!) {
    playlists(where: { users: { id: $id } }) {
      name
      users {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

[image]

But it doesn't work (i receive error 400 :/). But, with "static" query, it works as expected :

```
  {
    playlists(where: { users: { id: $id } }) {
      name
      users {
        id
     }
   }
```

[image]

I do not really understand why it doesn't work with query params.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you community!

Comment: Check the actual server response in the network tab of your browser's dev tools. The response will include the full validation error that is causing your issue. Most likely the wrong type on the variable.

Comment: Hi Daniel ! I've add some screenshot on my first post, i'm not sur the problem is from server

Comment: The problem is with your query, not the server. 400 means your query failed validation or there was a syntax error. The response from the server will tell you what went wrong. Could also be that your variable is missing.